# Show that the polynomial $x^{2}+1$ has no fixed prime divisor

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

An integer-valued polynomial $Q(x)$ has a **fixed divisor** $m$ if there is an integer $m>1$ such that
$\frac {Q(x)}{m}$ is also an integer-valued polynomial. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H#Fixed_divisors. If $m$ is a prime then we use the term **fixed prime divisor**.

I am interested in this problem:

Show that the polynomial $x^{2}+1$ has no fixed prime divisor.

Comment: If $m$ is a fixed prime divisor of $Q(x)$, then $Q(x)/m$ is **always** an integer ($\forall x \in \mathbb Z$). Can you prove the case $Q(x)=x^2+1$ using contradiction?

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is the desired prime factor, just set $x=p$. $p$ is surely not a divisor of $p^2+1$, hence $p$ cannot be a prime factor of $x^2+1$ in general.

Or formulated in terms of the definition of "fixed divisor" : $\frac{x^2+1}{p}$ is not integer-valued as the case $x=p$ shows.

We do not even need that $p$ is prime. This holds for every integer $p>1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2+1$ has a fixed prime divisor $p$, then $p \mid 1^2+1 = 2$ and $p \mid 2^2+1 = 5$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $Q(0)$. Can $Q(0)$ have any prime divisors, or in general any divisor $>1$?

Answer (score 1):

$P(0)=1$ is enough to say that there are no fixed divisor, prime or not.

> If an integer-valued polynomial has $1$ in its range then it has no fixed divisors.

**Edit**

Generalization: If an integer-valued polynomial has a *prime number* in its range, then it has no fixed number, excluded trivial cases like $P(x)=7x^2+7$

Comment: I am asking if there is a proof of your claim.

Comment: @Safwane It's obvious. If $P(x_0)=1$ then $\frac{P(x_0)}{m}$ will give as result the fraction $\frac{1}{m}$

Comment: @Ennar Corrected, thank you